# Windows sub authentication packages is not called

Tags: windows, authentication, credential-providers

I develop custom credential provider and my goal that the custom CP will authenticate using custom authentication provider.

I understand that implementation of sub authentication provider will be enough.

I took https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/security/authentication/msvsubauth and compile it with c++ project.

steps that i did :

1. add logs that indicates that the dll is called
2. copy the dll to system32
3. write the dll name(without .dll) in hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\lsa\msv1_0\auth0
4. reboot the machine

But still i cant see any indication that the dll has been called.

Answer (score 0):

The only time sub-auth packages does not work is if the dll is not registered properly in registry. The dll should be registered as Auth0. here's a sample registry format. You can save as `.reg` file and execute it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0]
"Auth0"="your-dll-name"
```

Other than this, I think everything should be fine given your context.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a dll name with 8 characters or less, and place the name of the dll in uppercase in the registry (no extension).

A simple working example can be found from one of the authors of Mimikatz here:
https://github.com/vletoux/SubAuth

Note the .reg file:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos]
> "Auth0"="SUBAUTH"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0]
> "Auth0"="SUBAUTH"